# Ajax method, undefined variable, two possible solutions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Sorry for the simple question, I am new to Javascript and Ajax.
Here is my code:

```
var rootURL = "http://localhost:8080/WineCellar/rest/wines";

var findById= function(id){
    var testWine;
    console.log('findById: ' + id);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: rootURL + '/' + id,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            console.log('findById success: '+ data.name);
            testWine = data;
        }
    });
    return testWine;
};


var myWine = findById(3);
console.log(myWine.name);
```

It gives the following console output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqmHQ.png

Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

myWine is undefined. How do I fix this? Is it possible there are ***two*** ways of overcoming this problem? Perhaps I need to add a parameter to the ajax method?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try using the fetch API ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API ) heres an example

```js
let YOUR_API = "https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/";
let cache;

window.onload = function () {
    fetch(YOUR_API)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((myJsonResponse) => {
        cache = myJsonResponse;
        console.log(cache);
        // the rest of the code that runs on this response
    });
};
```

Comment: It's the same fundamental problem - the request would still be asynchronous.

Comment: it seems like the users problem is "myWine is undefined. How do I fix this? " once myWine is defined he can process it however he needs to

Comment: Yes Mario, more specifically how do I define myWine in this context?

Comment: @MarioPerez it's undefined *because it's incorrectly returned*. Changing from `$.ajax` to `fetch` and not dealing with the asynchronisity, then nothing will change.